# PowerShell Access Network Share In Script As Different User

Tags: powershell

I am trying to access a domain network share in my PowerShell script that is currently running as NETWORK SERVICE. I have a domain user credential configured below.

```
$secStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$shareCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("DOMAIN\Username", $secStringPassword)
```

I would like to be able to run the following commands in the PowerShell script as the user specified above.

```
New-Item -Path "\\SERVER\Share\Folder" -ItemType Directory
Get-ChildItem "\\SERVER\Share\Folder"
```

Running the below is showing as not supported:

```
New-Item -Path "\\SERVER\Share\Folder" -ItemType Directory -Credential $shareCredential
```

Comment: Do you intend to leave the `$secStringPassword` var equal to `System.Security.SecureString` or do you wish to decrypt it in another section of your script

Comment: @NekoMusume I'm just going to leave it as is. I only need it to access the network share.

Answer (score 1):

"The New-Item cmdlet creates a new item and sets its value" If you're trying to connect to a share as a different user I suggest using new-psdrive first to create a mount as that user. This mounts that share as a drive so that it behaves more like a local location than a UNC path

```
New-PSDrive -Name "ShareNAME" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\Server\Share" -Credential $shareCredential
New-Item -Path ShareNAME:\Folder -ItemType Directory -Credential $shareCredential
Get-ChildItem ShareNAME:\Folder -Credential $shareCredential
```

Comment: I tried using the below, but I am getting the following error.

`New-PSDrive -Name "PSDriveShare" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\SERVER.sub.domain.com\Share\Folder" -Credential $shareCredential`

New-PSDrive : Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect 
all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again

Comment: This is exactly what it says. Unfortunately as far as I have been able to find, it is not possible to connect to a remote server share with multiple credentials simultaneously. 
If you know what share you have mapped with your standard user you can disconnect that share then connect with these credentials.
After you can reconnect with your standard user.

Comment: There is a GPO that is adding the Network Share on some machines, I am currently on a machine where this mapping is not present now so I can test further. Will report back soon.

Comment: Since GPO maps as part of the startup /login process you should be able to unmap then remap after script execution